# Is it possible to create a static tableview in ios5 without using storyboards?

Tags: iphone, ios5, uitableview, storyboard

I do not want to use storyboards in my app , but the static table views and the custom table view cells are really convenient. Is any way to use them in a non storyboard based application?

Comment: If you want to make an app without storyboard, you can! But you just can't drag&drop `UITableView` directly, instread you need to make it dynamically. For that you need to inherits `UITableViewController`. Me too wait for an answer, If its possible!:-)

Answer (score 0):

Some clarification first. Static or dynamic and custom tableviews are not existing expressions and I suppose you mix storyboard with InterfaceBuilder, but I guess I know what do you mean.

1. You can do anything without storyboards except storyboards. Just take in consideration that it will not work on devices with earlier IOS versions then IOS5, or better to say you couldn't deploy it.
2. "Static" tableview is simple an view of UITableViewController, which you can define in the .h file interface section like this:

   ```
   @interface MyListTableViewController : UITableViewController
   ```

It has a view which you can use as myListTableViewController.view. or attach any other view in your code or drag&drop a new one in XCode Interface Builder.

1. You can use any other kind of controllers like

   ```
   @interface MyNotTableViewController : UIViewController 
   <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
   ```

but you have to conform that it works with the tableview delegate and the data source delegate as you see attached to the line with brackets. From this point you can use the same method as I mentioned earlier to attach more tableviews. If you size this tableview full size of the screen or main view you get visually the same result as above in No2.